# Using SOCKS and system Firewall blocks IMAP/SMTP

Tags: email, ventura, firewall, proxy, socks

When I use the internal service of my university, I need to be inside the university network. So I have been using the SOCKS proxy and an SSH login server of my university for many years when I am out out the campus.

After upgrading my macOS to Ventura, I found that the use of SOCKS prevented me from sending e-mail messages on the Ventura Mac. I tried another Mac running with Monterey (and with the same e-mail accounts), finding that the issue did not happen on Monterey.

I also tried disabling the system firewall from System Settings on Ventura and enabling SOCKS later. It resolved the issue and so I conclude that mixing SOCKS and system firewall on Ventura (13.6.3) blocks STMP connection for some reason.

I use this script when I enable SOCKS.
https://gist.github.com/sheerun/3885694

I would like to know why the firewall on Ventura causes this problem and how I can use SOCKS and firewall at the same time.